# When is a projected length calculated via a pythagorean distance more accurate than an ellipsoidal length?

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm using spatialite 3.0.1 with the following test data (in EPSG: 4326):

```
Name        astext(geometry)    
----------  --------------------
Belitsa     POINT(23.563 41.947)
Malko Tarn  POINT(27.533 41.983)
Kotel       POINT(26.4752 42.938
```

My client demands I provide the projected st_length distance instead of geodesiclength.

(compare the following queries)

```
select a.name, b.name, st_length(transform(makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry), 32635)) from ProjCist a, ProjCist b;

Belitsa     Malko Tarn  329056.08890108 
...
```

versus

```
select a.name, b.name, geodesiclength(makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry)) from ProjCist a, ProjCist b;

Belitsa     Malko Tarn  329092.535472995 
...
```

The 50 meter difference in length, for our purposes, is *hugely* significant. Which is more correct? Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the local ellipsoid then it's a better distance approximation than the pythagorean distance, reason for that (in my knowledge) is quite simple : ellipsoid is meant to be a better approximation to distances. So unless you're working with a non-local ellipsoid, it's the way to go.